# Multiple Sessions or Multidimensional array?

Tags: php

I haven't got any data to benchmark this, so beforehand i'd like to know. What would you say would perform better with PHP with multiple users loading the same page?

1.100 sessions on a page each containing an array which each are unset at the end of the code 2.Multidimensional array: an array with 100 keys each containing an array.

Comment: Why do you even need a session if you unset it at the end of the code?

Comment: ok so, 100 arrays.  If multiple users are loading a page with 100 arrays would that have any major performance problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### overview

From reading your question I get the feeling that you don't understand what sessions are and how they work.

Just in case, I'm going to explicitly state a few things about sessions that you may or may not know.

- Sessions are created on a per-user basis, each user gets their own session key(s) and can access that data exclusively for the duration that the key persists.
- Session *data* is stored in a file on the server's filesystem
- The user stores a key to access their particular session in the session cookie

### need

Sessions are typically used to contain temporary, persistent, user-specific data. `$_SESSION` is an array, so you can store as many key-value pairs as you'd like with multidimensional arrays or objects.

The idea behind a session is to store all related data in a single session. If there are two sets of data that have independent state durations, then you should use two sessions.

Behind the scenes, a session is doing file IO, so there will be a necessary overhead in using a session.

### performance

as `$_SESSION` isn't all that different from any other array, there isn't going to be a significant difference in code between using a single multidimensional array, and using 100 arrays. There *will* be a significant difference in the amount of read-write time used to open/close the sessions. If there's no reason to have the data in separate sessions, use one session and alias the data as needed:

```
$foo = $_SESSION['foo'];
//do stuff with $foo
$_SESSION['foo'] = $foo;
```

Any arrays you create in global scope are automatically going to be multidimensional arrays anyway due to the `$GLOBALS` array (not that you should access them from there).

### tl; dr

Don't use more than one session unless you have multiple data sets that need to persist separate from each other.

No premature optimization. Test instead of guess.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that loading 100 separate files of data for each user will incure the overhead of having to locate AND load those files, PLUS the parseing overhead in PHP. If you can load one larger file, it's almost ALWAYS going to be more efficient than loading multiple small files.

But of course, you'll have to benchmark. What might be slow on one system may be ultrafast on yours, and any answer you get here that says "you must do it This One True Way(tm)" is going to be flat wrong.

Answer (score 0):

These are both basically identical. There may be *slightly* more memory use from 100 separate arrays than an array with 100 arrays as elements - but that also depends on whether that's an associative or enumerated array.

Realistically though, for storage purposes, memory use is identical.

Whether one is better than the other for a particular script will depend on the script. If you're putting a large multi-dimensional array through `foreach` that makes a copy and consumes more memory than `foreach`ing each member independently or conditionally.